# How do I create histogram with a probability y-axis rather than frequency y-axis in R?

Tags: r, statistics

[Histogram that I want to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOL1n.gif)

How do I create a histogram with a probability y-axis rather than frequency y-axis **in R**

I'm very new to R, so I apologize in advance.

Do I need to calculate the probability first with a function in R. And then, input the result in the probability histogram function?

or
there is a function in R that can calculate all at once? (Please help me with the function)

Here is my data

```
 sample(rep(1:10, each=10))


  [1]  6  1  7  7  9  9  3  4  6  1  1  2 10  5  9  7  8  5  3  6  1  4  4  2  2
 [26]  6  3 10  7  8  1  2  2  9  5  9  5  2  2  8  6  6 10  9  3 10  8  5  5 10
 [51]  8  9  7 10  4  1  3 10  1  3  7  2  2  2  9  8  7  8  8  1  1  3  9  8  7
 [76]  6  6  3  9  4  4  1 10  8  3  6  5  7  7  5  6 10  5  5  3  4 10  4  4  4
```

**Fyi,** I have a task about the discrete uniform distribution

Comment: either use `hist(sample(10,1000, TRUE), probability = TRUE)` or `hist(sample(10,1000, TRUE), freq = FALSE)`

Comment: Thanks for your help, I get it now. :)

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is divide by you numbers by the total numbers of observations. Frequency/count = probability. So just run a histogram with this new variable.